# I'm not able to write on CSV file using Python's Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My goal is writing a Python script which can retrieve specific data from a website.

Specifically I have to extract these data:

```
<span class="street-address" itemprop="streetAddress">191, Corso Peschiera</span>
```

and

```
<div itemprop="telephone" class="tel elementPhone">0184 662271</div>
```

Only the number and the address of course!

While I try to extract plain 'div' or 'a' or 'href' I have no issues, but I'm not able to improve my research.

Here is my code... I'm not able to write to a file unless I pass only an argument like `soup.find_all('a')` to `bs4`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.paginegialle.it/ricerca/lidi%20balneari/Torino?')
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
dia = soup.find_all('<div itemprop="telephone" class="tel elementPhone"></div>')

for link in soup.find_all('<div itemprop="telephone" class="tel elementPhone"></div>'):
    print (dia)

documento=open("mbsprovalive.csv","w")
    documento.write(dia)
        documento.close()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where have you read that `soup.find_all('<div itemprop="telephone" class="tel     elementPhone"></div>')` would work? Have you looked at the return value of this call? Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: Start by reading the documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all. The first positional argument to `find_all()` is the tag name, not some html snippet. To filter based on attributes you'd pass in suitable keyword arguments, or a dict as the `attrs` arg.

Comment: @Tomalak trough the documentation i was able to build a script who can find all 'div' or all 'a' but not a more complex expression as i stated in the answer.

Comment: You have not read the documentation then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`bs4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)'s `attrs` field to specify exactly what class is of your interest like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

data = requests.get('your url here').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")

for i,j in zip(soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'street-address'}), soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'tel elementPhone'})):
    print i.text, j.text
```

This should work!

Comment: hi @coder! ty for help! this is the output  >>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>>
>>> data = requests.get('https://www.paginegialle.it/ricerca/lidi%20balneari/Roma%20(RM)?').text
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
>>>
>>> for i,j in zip(soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'street-address'}), soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'tel elementPhone'})):
...     print (i.text, j.text)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: I run your code and faced no issue. The problem is that when using `requests` module in python you must never omit the **http** part from the url. So by defining data as: `data = requests.get('https://www.paginegialle.it/ricerca/lidi%20balneari/Roma%20(RM)?%27').text`   you shouldn't have any issue!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code perfectly functioning. There are only some annoying formatting issues.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
r = requests.get('https://www.paginegialle.it/ricerca/pizzerie/Milano?
mr=50')
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
with open('mbsprprova.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
fieldnames = ['nome', 'indirizzo', 'telefono']
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
for i,j,z in zip(soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'street-address'}), soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'telelementPhone'}), soup.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop':'name'})):
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'nome': z.text, 'telefono': j.text, 'indirizzo': i.text})
```